# NVARCHAR(MAX) string appears to have 6326 characters but won't PRINT them all

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-mail

I am writing a stored procedure to use the `sp_send_dbmail` system stored procedure to send an HTML email. I have used this procedure before but have not run into this problem before. I am using the build method laid out [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99326/sp-send-dbmail-stored-procedure-send-with-attachment)

From online I believe that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` should hold a maximum of 2 147 483 647 characters ([ref](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic647815-145-1.aspx))

However, when I build my output if I `PRINT` the output it does not return the full string.

I have tested my SQL separately and this returns as expected.

Clearly I have a mistake but can someone point what it is please!

The script is:

```
Declare @RawPart varchar(30);
Declare @PO varchar(30);
Declare @NL varchar(12)='<br/>';
DECLARE @BodyHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
Declare @SubjectText varchar(200);
Declare @StaffEmail varchar(50);
Declare @MrpDate varchar(12);


Set @MrpDate=(Select convert (varchar(12),[SnapshotDate],103) from [dbo].[MrpReqCtl] )

set @StaffEmail='SOMEPLACE@DOMAIN.co.uk';
set @SubjectText ='Schedule Update from MRP Email';
Set @PO='106277';
Set @RawPart=(Select Distinct  MStockCode From dbo.PorMasterDetail Where PurchaseOrder=@PO and LineType=1)


--N'<p>Attention From the Mrp run '+@MrpDate+N'</p><p>Has Detected Changed to the following Schedules</>'
----Define Customer Schedule Table
--         +
Set @BodyHTML=      N'<H1>Customer Schedules</H1>' +
                    N'<table border="1">' +
                    N'<tr><th>Sales Order</th><th>Line</th><th>Ship Date</th><th>Customer</th><th>Stockcode</th><th>Os Qty</th><th>Status</th>'

--Stage 2 Customer Order Details Table
                     +cast( (Select SalesOrder, SalesOrderLine, convert(varchar(12),MLineShipDate,103) as DispatchDate
                                , Customer,rtrim(StockCode)+' - '+ rtrim(F.StockCodeDesc) ,cast(OutstandingQty as int) OutstandingQty
                                ,Case When MLineShipDate<datediff(d,0,getdate())  Then 'Arrs' else '' end as Status 
                                From [dbo].[CHCIW_ForwardOrders] F
                                Where F.StockCode IN (
                                                        Select BC.TopLevel
                                                        FROM         dbo.K3_vwBOMCosting BC
                                                        inner Join dbo.InvMaster I On BC.StockCode=I.StockCode
                                                        Where [TopLevel] like 'MG%' and I.StockCode=@RawPart )
                                        and MLineShipDate<dateadd(m,3,datediff(d,0,getdate()) )
                                Order By MLineShipDate
                                For xml Path('tr'), Type) as nvarchar(max))+  N'</table>' ;
Set @BodyHTML=rtrim(@BodyHTML)

Print len(@BodyHTML)
Print @BodyHTML
```

However, the output is:

```
6326

<H1>Customer Schedules</H1><table border="1"><tr><th>Sales Order</th><th>Line</th><th>Ship Date</th><th>Customer</th><th>Stockcode</th><th>Os Qty</th><th>Status</th><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>5</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>30/10/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>249</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>177</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>10/11/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>846</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>7</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>10/11/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>468</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>179</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>17/11/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>7020</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>9</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>17/11/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>468</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>181</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>24/11/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>7020</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>11</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>30/11/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>720</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>183</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>01/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>7020</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>41</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>07/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>1224</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>185</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>08/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>7020</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>43</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>14/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>252</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>187</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>15/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>7020</OutstandingQty><Status>Arrs</Status></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>189</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>22/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>7020</OutstandingQty><Status/></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>191</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>29/12/2017</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>10920</OutstandingQty><Status/></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010879</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>45</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>04/01/2018</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>MG16311504501 - VW 1.0L EU6ZD Machined -1565<OutstandingQty>252</OutstandingQty><Status/></tr><tr><SalesOrder>010158</SalesOrder><SalesOrderLine>193</SalesOrderLine><DispatchDate>05/01/2018</DispatchDate><Customer>BORG02</Customer>XXXXXXXXX507 - SOME DECRIPTIVE TEXT XXXXX<OutstandingQty>10920</OutstandingQty><Status/
```

Comment: Just a question why is this a duplicate. My datatype was NVARCHAR (Max)? The cause of the problem I can see as the same but I did not use that answer because if the different datatype

Comment: Ian: your question is not a duplicate, but not for the reason you are stating. What matters here is the length of the string. Because you have less than 8001 characters, and assuming that they all fit within the Code Page specified by the Database's default Collation, you _can_ use `PRINT` and do not need to mess with any other mechanism to break the string into 4000 character chunks to print individually. Not sure why this was closed as a dupe. Also, you can either edit a comment within 5 minutes of posting it, or you can add a new one and then delete the original.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a limitation of what can be displayed in the "Messages" tab via either `PRINT` or `RAISERROR`. They can either show 4000 characters of `NVARCHAR` data or 8000 character of `VARCHAR` data.

There are a few ways around this, such as breaking the string into chunks that will work within those limits via a `CURSOR`. But, if:

- you have less than 8001 characters (which you do), *AND*
- you do not have any characters in that string that won't fit into the Code Page specified by the Database's default Collation

then you could just convert the string to `VARCHAR(8000)`:

```
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), @BodyHTML);
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'A'
    + REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), N'_'), 7998)
    + N'Z123';

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @String);
```

If you execute that and then check the "Messages" tab, you should have a line that starts with "A___", then plenty more "_"s, and then ends with "___Z". You should not see the "123" (as those are characters 8001 - 8003). If you place your cursor at the end of that line (just to the right of the "Z"), then the "Col" and "Ch" values in the blue bar at the bottom of SSMS should both be **8001**.

P.S. Using either `VARCHAR(8000)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` should be fine. I haven't seen a difference in behavior between them *for this particular scenario*.

---

Also, to clarify the datatype limit: 2,147,483,647 is the maximum number of **bytes** that can be stored in an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column. Since `NVARCHAR` is UTF-16 data, it uses either 2 or 4 bytes per each "character", with most typically used characters falling in the 2-byte group. Meaning, you can get *at most* HALF of that byte limit as characters, if all characters are of the 2-byte variety. If any characters are the 4-byte variety, then the total number of *characters* it can hold decreases since the maximum number of bytes does not change.

Also, the documentation is incorrect in that it says that "2,147,483,647 is the maximum number of **characters**".  I will submit a correct for that.

Comment: CAST your output to XML and you'll be able to see the full value

Comment: @Nic Cast to XML for a `PRINT` statement? The O.P. wants to use `PRINT`, not `SELECT`. And if using `SELECT`, then the string wouldn't have been truncated as it isn't large enough for that.

Comment: they'll never get the full string using print..makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the suggested solution. In this case will just send the email. But the work round is good to knon

Comment: @Nic regarding your statement of "_they'll never get the full string using print_": I don't see how not given that it definitely works. I even updated my answer with some example code showing that it works.

Comment: @IanW Yer welcome. I just updated my answer with some example code and made the explanation a little clearer.

Comment: Your example code proves that you can't see the whole string. Even the documentation states that it can be a max of 8000 characters, so I'm not sure how a string longer than that could be printed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql

Comment: @Nic My example proves that the _limit_ is 8000. But to my knowledge, 6326 is _less_ than 8000. Meaning, my example proves beyond any doubt that the O.P. will be able to display the entire contents of their string variable. Not sure why you are claiming that 6326 characters is more than 8000.

Comment: No, but it'd be trivial for it to be longer than the current statement, at which point OP would be back asking why they can't print more than 8000 characters.

Comment: @Nic While it is true that a string _can_ be longer, the string in question is _not_ longer. And, if you actually read my answer (like the O.P. has done) then you would realize that the O.P. would not be asking themselves why strings over 8000 characters are truncated ;-)